# C Program for reading test results

Tags: c

I wonder if anyone can help?

I am doing some basic C programming as part of a degree module, we have been asked to create a few scripts.

I am completely new to this.

I need a script that gives the correct grade for a user input.

The grades are:

- 70%+ outputs A
- 60%+ outputs B
- 50%+ outputs C
- 40+ outputs D
- Less than 40% outputs F

(e.g 63% would output B).

Can someone please help me with a code example of this and recommend some good websites or books to read in order to learn the basics quickly and easily.

Thank you!

My current code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int result;
    char grade;

    printf( "Please enter a number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &result );
    if (result = 70<=100){
    printf("A", grade);};
    if (result = 60<=69){
    printf("B", grade);};
    if (result = 50<=59){
    printf("C", grade);};
    if (result = 40<=49){
    printf("D", grade);};
    if (result = 0<=49){
    printf("F", grade);};

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try it yourself, my friend. And when you are stuck at something, we are happy to help you.

Comment: I am stuck, that's why I'm asking, why I asked for an example to what looks like an easy one and some recommended websites...

Comment: If you are facing an error, show us some code and explain where you are stuck. Then we might be able to help you.

Comment: if ... else if ... else

Comment: I have tried it a few times, but I am getting every grade come out when I run it. That's why I asked for help or somewhere with good tutorials. My current code has been added above... I am getting the result of ABCDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using if statements and you want to compare a result you should use == instead of =.
With = you are assigning a value to a variable and == compares between to values.

You can also not compare two things at the same time like:

```
if (result = 70<=100)
```

You need to check if result <= 100 AND result >= 70

To make multiple checks in an if statement you need to use && (AND) or || (OR)

In your case you should use:

```
if(result <= 100 && result >= 70)
```

See:

http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-logical-operator/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/if_else_statement_in_c.htm

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have managed to solve it now, was just mixing up the modulus. Had a quick look at the sites as well, they look great. Thank you.